# Can we have one string for different storyboard,XIB,Clases localization for respective language?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, storyboard, localizable.strings

My project will be having `internalization` with 10 different language.My question is, I have four different `storyboard` file and localized it. So Every `storyboard` is having localized string file for respective language. Can we merge respective language string file together in one for respective langauge? 
eg. so en.lproj will be having one string file for all string (string from `XIB`,`Storyboard`,`classes`). Please, suggest me. is it good way to do this? Reason for changing single string file to reduce the size of the app.

Update:
Suppose: A, B, C three diff storyboard. every storyboard will be having en.string,ja.string,fr.string file. I want to merge these file in one file for respective language. So it's mean for all storyboard only three file will be there  which are en.string,ja.string,fr.string only. I hope it's make clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but in general you can (and often should) have one strings file pr. language (i.e. Localizable.strings). Normally, you don't have to localize the storyboard and xib files - simply set your texts in the view controller code with `NSLocalizedString`.

An exception to this is if you localize to languages with different reading direction (like arabic). In this case you might want to localize your UI files to reorder the UI elements. However, if your views are not too complex it might still be better to do the reordering in code to avoid having to maintain multiple UI files.